# Search with pagination in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, pagination

Hello I am attempting to do a search with pagination in Code Igniter its working properly for first page, but when the user tries to click the link to the next page its shows pagination numbers greater than actual search result. Plus the data not show properly.

**My Controller:**

```
public function search() {
    try {

        $data = new stdClass();

        $name = $this->input->post('name');

        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "gadmin_user/search";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->Gadmin_model->search_count($name);
        $config["per_page"] = 10;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '<li>&lt;';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data->users = $this->Gadmin_model->serach_by_user($name,$config["per_page"], $page);
        $data->links = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view('gadmin/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('gadmin/user/search', $data);
        $this->load->view('gadmin/templates/footer');

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
```

**My Model:**

```
public function search_count($keyword){


    $q =  $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('users')
                        ->where("name LIKE '%$keyword%'")
                        ->get();

    return $q -> num_rows();

}


public function serach_by_user($keyword,$start, $limit){

    $search =  $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('users')
                        ->where("name LIKE '%$keyword%'")
                        ->limit($start, $limit)
                        ->get();

    if($search->num_rows() > 0){
        return $search->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the limit start use this, and the limit is $config["per_page"]

```
  $c=1;
        if($page){
            $c = $page;
            $limit_start = $limit * ($c - 1);
        }
```